# Do I need to send my token to server

Tags: ios

I am implementing Push notification in my app.
I have created the certificate and Profiles as per apple guidelines.
I am also able to get token in
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:  method

I am using a PHP server to generate PUSH notification.
Now I am not clear, Do I need to send the apptoken back to my push server.
And how send token to server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should implement a web service exposed by the server to allow the client app to send its push token to the server.

Without the token your server has no idea where to send the notification.

Comment: As a general point though doesn't it depend on whether or not the notifications are targeted to specific devices? If the OP only wants to send out a general message to every one using the app the token isn't necessary?

Comment: Is there any standard set of parameters for sending to server or I have to send only token and the app id to Server API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your token received in your method `- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken` like this

```
 NSString *tokenPush = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

And after to send it to your server for to keep it. After, when you need to send any push notification to any device, you will need to use this tokenPush.

Answer (score 0):

Hey after getting token yo have to send it to server via web services.below i have given an example of websevices using ASHIHttp framework.Save this token in database if you have to send notification to more then one devices.

-(void)savePlayerDataOnServer:(NSString *)facebookName
{

```
appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSLog(@"Tokennn %@", [appdelegate string]);


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost@"yourscripturl"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *fbnameinside = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",facebookName];

NSLog(@"globalmailID in savePlayerDataOnServer %@",globalmailID);


[request setPostValue:fbnameinside forKey:@"PlayerName"];
[request setPostValue:globalmailID forKey:@"PlayerEmail"];

[request setPostValue:[appdelegate string] forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response in savePlayerDataOnServer: %@", responseString);
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error in savePlayerDataOnServer: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

}

Comment: I used ASHIHttp for my app you can also use different aproach